# How to increase readCharacteristic of Ble device?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app that downlaod all characteristic from a BLE device. This device storage in your local memory 10 distinct double values, every 3ms.

So in 1 second the BLE device has storage 333 row (every row have 10 values).

My Android app, download this values but I can to downlaod one rows of second or little less. In this mode I can't never to download all the information of this BLE device.

Now there is any way to increase the frequency of scan o read this characteristic ?

this is my Service that downlaod the characteristic of BLE device:

```
public class BlePowerService extends Service {
    public DbLayer db;
    Setting settingApp;
    List<ScanFilter> filters;
    String[] stringSequence = new String[] {CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING, CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_STRING};
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    BluetoothGatt mGatt;
    BluetoothDevice currDevice;
    static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 500;
    static String SPLIT_CHAR =";";
    BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    Handler mHandler;
    int ReadQueueIndex;
    List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> ReadQueue;
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic caratteristicaDaLeggere;
    ScanSettings settings;
    Integer ultimaForzaLetta,ultimaTemperaturaLetta;
    boolean continuaLetturaForza, continuaLetturaTemperatura;
    boolean isReading = true;
    String LOG_CODE = "NOTIFSRV";
    GattClientCallback gattClientCallback;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_COARSE_LOCATION = 1;


    public BlePowerService() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mHandler = new Handler();

        Context sharedContext = null;
        try {
            sharedContext = this.createPackageContext(
                    "com.care.devicesensor",
                    Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE);
            if (sharedContext == null) {
                return;
            }
            db=new DbLayer(sharedContext);
            db.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String error = e.getMessage();
          //  Log.d(LOG_CODE,"DB error : " + error);
            return;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        try {
            //RECUPERO LE IMPOSTAZIONI SETTATE DALL'UTENTE
            settingApp = db.fetchSetting();
            if (settingApp != null && settingApp.getAddressBleSX()!=null) {
                //POSSO FILTRARE DIRETTAMENTE PER L'UUID DEL DISPOSITIVO MEMORIZZATO
                //DALL'UTENTE
                ScanFilter.Builder scanFilterMac =
                        null;
                    scanFilterMac = new ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceAddress(settingApp.getAddressBleSX());
                if(filters==null)
                    filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
                //if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                filters.add(scanFilterMac.build());
                //}
                //FILTRO ANCHE PER LA CARATTERISTICA DI FORZA
                ScanFilter filter = null;
                    filter = new ScanFilter.Builder().setServiceUuid(ParcelUuid.fromString(CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING)).build();
                filters.add(filter);

                final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
                    mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();
                //mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
                    mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                    settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                            .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_POWER)
                            .build();
                scanLeDevice(true);
                mTimer = new Timer();
                //ogni 2 ore
                continuaLetturaForza = true;
                continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;

                int nSecondi = settingApp.getFrequenzaDownload()!= null ? settingApp.getFrequenzaDownload() : 1;
                mTimer.schedule(timerTask,5000);
                //mTimer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 1000 * nSecondi);
                //mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate (timerTask, 10000, 1000 * nSecondi);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
           // Log.e("POWER_SERVICE", e.getMessage());
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private Timer mTimer;

    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //LEGGO TUTTI I DATI DAL SENSORE FINCHE CI SONO VALORI
             int counter = 0;
            while(continuaLetturaForza || continuaLetturaTemperatura){
                counter++;
                //Log.v("CICLO WHILE", counter+"");
                if (currDevice != null) {

                    if(ReadQueue!= null && ReadQueue.size()>0){
                        int index =0;
                        for(index=0; index < ReadQueue.size(); index++){
                            if(mGatt!=null){
                                isReading = mGatt.readCharacteristic(ReadQueue.get(index));
                                while(isReading){
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(1);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                            }else{
                                continuaLetturaForza = false;
                                continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }else{
                    //provo a ricollegarmi al dispositivo probabile, abbia perso la connessione con esso
                    scanLeDevice(true);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    if(currDevice == null && counter == 25){
                        //in questo caso non è riuscito a trovare il dispositivo BLE
                        //esco dal ciclo
                        continuaLetturaForza = false;
                        continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                        continue;
                    }
                }

            }

            if(gattClientCallback!=null && mGatt != null)
                gattClientCallback.disconnectGattServer();
            mTimer.cancel();
            stopSelf();
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("stopService"));
        }

        public void stopTask() {

            if (timerTask != null) {

                Log.d("TIMER", "timer canceled");
                timerTask.cancel();
            }
        }
    };


    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        //VERIFICO SE IL DEVICE è QUELLO CHE VOGLIO IO
        if (mGatt == null && settingApp != null
                && device.getAddress().equals(settingApp.getAddressBleSX())) {
            currDevice = device;
            gattClientCallback = new GattClientCallback();
            mGatt = currDevice.connectGatt(getBaseContext(), false, gattClientCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    Handler h = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
                    // Although you need to pass an appropriate context
                    h.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                          //  Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());
                                connectToDevice(device);

                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }


    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
           // Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
           // Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = null;
               btDevice = result.getDevice();
            connectToDevice(btDevice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
           Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    private class GattClientCallback extends BluetoothGattCallback {

        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            try{
                super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                //Log.i("tag", "onConnectionStateChange newState: " + newState);

                if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_FAILURE) {
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection Gatt failure status " + status);
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            gatt.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }
                    return;
                } else if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                    // handle anything not SUCCESS as failure
                    Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Connection not GATT sucess status " + status);
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            gatt.close();
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }
                    return;
                }

                if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                    //Log.i("INFO", "Connected to device " + gatt.getDevice().getAddress());
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                    Log.i("INFO", "Disconnected from device");
                    if(mGatt == null){

                    }else{
                        try {
                            mGatt.close();
                            mGatt = null;
                            currDevice = null;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.d("", "close ignoring: " + e);
                        }
                        mGatt = null;
                    }

                }
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
                continuaLetturaForza = true;
                continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;
            }
        }

        public void disconnectGattServer() {

            continuaLetturaForza = true;
            continuaLetturaTemperatura = true;
            isReading = false;
            if (mGatt == null) {

            }
            else{
                try{
                    mGatt.disconnect();
                   // mGatt.close();
                }catch(Exception e){
                    mGatt = null;
                }

            }
            //mGatt = null;
            //currDevice = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);

            if (status != BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
             //   Log.i("INFO", "Device service discovery unsuccessful, status " + status);
                return;
            }

            List<BluetoothGattCharacteristic> matchingCharacteristics =
                    BluetoothUtils.findCharacteristics(gatt,stringSequence);
            if (matchingCharacteristics.isEmpty()) {
              //  Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE","Unable to find characteristics.");
                return;
            }else {

                ReadQueue = new ArrayList<>();
                for (BluetoothGattCharacteristic characterist : matchingCharacteristics) {
                    ReadQueue.add(characterist);
                }
                //ReadQueueIndex = 0;
                //ReadCharacteristics(ReadQueueIndex);
            }



        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status);
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                String valoreRestituito = characteristic.getStringValue(0);
                if(valoreRestituito==null){
                    int i = 0;
                    i = i + 1;
                    return;
                }
                //SPLITTO PER IL CARATTERE ;
                String[] arrayValori = valoreRestituito.split(SPLIT_CHAR);
                //1 valore è l ID
                try{
                    int id = new Integer(arrayValori[0]);
                    //VERIFICO SE STO LEGGENDO TEMPERATURA O FORZA
                    if(characteristic.getUuid().equals(CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_UUID)){
                        /*Log.v("CARATTERISTICA", "*****************************************");
                        Log.v("FORZA", "*****************************************");*/
                        if(ultimaForzaLetta!= null && ultimaForzaLetta == id){
                            continuaLetturaForza = false;
                            isReading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        ultimaForzaLetta = id;
                    }else if(characteristic.getUuid().equals( CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_UUID)){
                        /*Log.v("CARATTERISTICA", "*****************************************");
                        Log.v("TEMPERATURA", "*****************************************");*/
                        if(ultimaTemperaturaLetta!= null && ultimaTemperaturaLetta == id){
                            continuaLetturaTemperatura = false;
                            isReading = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        ultimaTemperaturaLetta = id;
                    }

                    SensorData mSenData = new SensorData();
                    mSenData.setIdType(id);
                    mSenData.setValue1(arrayValori[1]);
                    mSenData.setValue2(arrayValori[2]);
                    mSenData.setValue3(arrayValori[3]);
                    mSenData.setValue4(arrayValori[4]);
                    mSenData.setValue5(arrayValori[5]);
                    mSenData.setValue6(arrayValori[6]);
                    mSenData.setValue7(arrayValori[7]);
                    mSenData.setValue8(arrayValori[8]);
                    //TO-DO HO COMMENTATO QUESTA RIGA DI CODICE
                    // mSenData.setIdType(st.getId());
                    mSenData.setCharacteristic(characteristic.getUuid().toString());
                    mSenData.setValueTimestamp(db.getDateTime(true));

                    db.insertSensorData(mSenData);

                    EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent("update"));

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage());
                }
                isReading = false;

            } else {
                isReading = false;
                Log.e("ERROR_SERVICE", "Characteristic read unsuccessful, status: " + status);

                disconnectGattServer();

                return;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onDestroy() {
        try {
            db.close();
            Log.d(LOG_CODE,"DB connection closed" );

            mTimer.cancel();
            timerTask.cancel();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

The service works correctly but is to slow.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do more than one read request per connection interval. Since 3 ms is much less than the minimum allowed connection interval, what you're trying to do seems impossible. You will have to make your protocol more efficient, for example by letting the peripheral send a stream of notifications. This way you can achieve multiple peckets per connection event.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Can I know what is the minimun times to connection interval ?